# Moving the player with Transform.translate at a 45 degree angle?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
{
    transform.Translate(-Vector3.right * distance);
}
else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.right * distance);
}
```

Would like to make it so that, when the left / right arrow key is pressed, the player moves left / right but at a 45 degree angle. Is there any way to use transform.translate with an x and y coordinate, instead of Vector3.right? Thanks

Comment: Can you not just rotate first, then translate, then rotate back?

Comment: Possibly, was just wondering if there is a way to use x and y instead of Vector2.right as it would be much easier

Comment: its not a `unity`, read tags please

Comment: I suppose you could add the vectors together like `transform.Translate((-Vector3.right + Vector3.up).Normalize() * distance);`

Answer (score 1):

Sure, any normalized vector is a directional vector, you arent just limited to the right, up, forward ones.

```
Vector3 direction = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 0f).normalized;

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    transform.Translate(direction * distance);

else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    transform.Translate(direction * distance);
```